# Windows: Odoo not working : ImportError :No module named tools

Tags: python, pip, odoo, odoo-8

I have manually tried to install odoo in my windows system using souce link https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/src/odoo_8.0.latest.zip .Could any one help me to figure out why the following error was resulted while running odoo.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "odoo.py", line 160, in <module>
main()
File "odoo.py", line 156, in main
import openerp
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\__init__.py", line 76, in             <module>
import modules
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\modules\__init__.py", line  27, in <module>
from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\modules\graph.py", line 32, in <module>
import openerp.osv as osv
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\osv\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
import osv
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 23, in <module>
from .orm import Model, TransientModel, AbstractModel
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 5, in <module>
from ..models import (
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\models.py", line 61, in  <module>
from . import api
File "C:\Projects\odoo8\odoo-8.0-20160613\openerp\api.py", line 71, in <module>
from openerp.tools import frozendict, classproperty
ImportError: No module named tools
```

Python version : 2.7.9

Comment: I have manually followed the steps from https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pls ensure your openerp folder has a directory named 'tools', if not try this link to download new instance
for windows: https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/exe/
for Linux: https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/src/

Comment: Yes, There is no folder named tools. But still i want to run odoo from the source code not with executable file. So, can you suggest me any tips for that.

Comment: Use this link https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/src/ to download new instance, extract it and either copy 'tools' folder from openerp directory to you instance or use this new instance as default.